# Getting error in console but don't know where the code is?

Tags: android

I'm trying to follow the steps on this website:

http://apcmag.com/getting-started-with-medroid.htm

to create a HelloAndroid application.  However, instead of using the virtual device I want to use my s3.  I put the s3 in usb debugging mode and made sure the run config had it selected.

My problem is that when I run it, it gives me this error, which is the same error I got from a completely different and totally unrelated project:

```
[2013-09-05 21:18:02 - google-play-services_lib] ------------------------------
[2013-09-05 21:18:02 - google-play-services_lib] Android Launch!
[2013-09-05 21:18:02 - google-play-services_lib] adb is running normally.
[2013-09-05 21:18:02 - google-play-services_lib] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-09-05 21:18:02 - google-play-services_lib] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2013-09-05 21:18:02 - google-play-services_lib] Performing sync
[2013-09-05 21:18:08 - google-play-services_lib] Uploading google-play-services_lib.apk onto device 'd20eb13c'
[2013-09-05 21:18:08 - google-play-services_lib] Installing google-play-services_lib.apk...
[2013-09-05 21:18:15 - google-play-services_lib] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2013-09-05 21:18:15 - google-play-services_lib] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2013-09-05 21:18:15 - google-play-services_lib] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.google.android.gms' in a shell.
[2013-09-05 21:18:15 - google-play-services_lib] Launch canceled!
```

I'm not even using google-play-services!  I'm just trying to run that helloworld app on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your package name is "com.google.android.gms". Rename your package name to something unique like "com.companyname.appname" and not googles.

Comment: How do I rename the package name?

Comment: I opened package explorer and deleted the google play services _lib file, now the only thing that is left is the helloandroid package.  however i get a different error when running it now .  sigh.

Comment: The package name is mentioned in the androidmanifest.xml file. check the name "package=" under the manifest tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just Uninstall the app, clean and run again
This happened to me today it was due to an different version of my app that was loaded already.